# How to optimize my aggregation code ? (Python)

Tags: python, performance, if-statement, optimization, aggregate

In order to continue to learn and progress, I am wondering about this code :

```
def replace_titles(x) :
    title = x['Title']
    if title in ['Dr'] : # Dr to Mr or Mrs
        return 'Mr' if x['Sex'] == 'male' else 'Mrs'
    elif title in ['Don', 'Sir', 'Capt', 'Col', 'Major', 'Rev', 'Jonkheer', 'Mr'] : # Male titles to Mr or Children
        return 'Children' if x['Age'] < 14.5 else 'Mr'
    elif title in ['Master'] : # Master to Children
        return 'Children'
    elif title in ['Lady', 'Countess', 'Dona', 'Mme', 'Miss', 'Mlle', 'Ms', 'Mrs'] : # Female titles to Children or Mrs
        return 'Children' if x['Age'] < 14.5 else 'Mrs'
    else :
        return title
```

I want to aggregate titles into more meaningful categories and list all the children < 14.5 years.

How do you think I can optimize this code ? *(shorter and more efficient)*

Maybe with match-case in Python 3.10.x ?

Thank you

Comment: It might help if you described what your code is supposed to do.

Comment: To make it a little more efficient you should use sets `('Dr')` instead of lists `['Dr']` for checking with `in`. Also you may want to update the logic, like check age -> check sex, check title, but this depends on the data you expect

Comment: Just use a match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want it ***shorter*** maybe you could do it in just one line with [*ternary conditional operator*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator)

```py
def replace_titles(x):
    title = x['Title']
    return 'Children' if x['Age'] < 14.5 else 'Mr' if x['Sex'] == 'male' and title in ['Dr', 'Don', 'Sir', 'Capt', 'Col', 'Major', 'Rev', 'Jonkheer', 'Mr'] else 'Mrs' if title in ['Lady', 'Countess', 'Dona', 'Mme', 'Miss', 'Mlle', 'Ms', 'Mrs'] else title
```